# Anchor plus href and onclick event (tracking)

Tags: jquery, url, onclick, statistics, href

i got the following anchors to go to the target site and to track the user for stats:

```
<a href="http://target.tld" target="_blank" onclick="$('<img></img>').attr({src: 'stats.php?my_param=value'}); return true;">Foo</a>

<a href="http://target.tld" target="_self" onclick="$('<img></img>').attr({src: 'stats.php?my_param=value'}); return true;">Foo</a>
```

The first one generates a Status of *200 Ok* for the img (_blank), but the status of the second one (_self) is *(canceled)*.

Can someone tell me why, and is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: First, what is exactly the goal of your script? You want to know where the user clicked?

Comment: yup, just to track the user

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid `on*` event attributes. If you've got jQuery, use it to bind your events. Secondly, it looks like you're creating the `img` element with the goal of making a GET request to track the click. Instead, just use jQuery to fire off the request.

```
<a href="http://target.tld" target="_blank" class="track-link" data-value="foo">Foo</a>    
<a href="http://target.tld" target="_self" class="track-link" data-value="bar">Foo</a>
```

```js
$('.track-link').click(function() {
    var trackValue = $(this).data('value');
    $.get('/stats.php', { my_param: trackValue });
});
```

**Update**

Try using the `mousedown` event to ensure the request gets sent before the page transfers:

```
$('.track-link').mousedown(function() {
    var $link = $(this);

    if (!$link.data('request-sent')) {
        $.get(
            '/stats.php', 
            { my_param: $link.data('value') },
            function() {
                $link.data('request-sent', true);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

**Update #3**

```
$('.track-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    $.get(
        '/stats.php', 
        { my_param: $link.data('value') },
        function() {
            window.location.assign($link.prop('href'));
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. Are you also able to tell me, why the request get canceled if i use _self as target and if the href url open in a new window, the window gets loaded with no errors

Comment: I thought it will work, but it wont. The same result as with the onclick img :(

Comment: Hmm sometimes it works and sometime not, i guess its a runtime problem. I could solve the problem with window.location, but some pop up blockers making problems with window.location

Comment: I would imagine the problem is because the link is followed before the request is completed. Try my latest update.

Comment: Thanks, but does "window.location" make any problems with popup blockers etc?

Comment: No, as it will not open a new window.

Comment: So its not possible to track it without window.location? Cause i dont want to change the way how the user comes to a sites, it should be with href and not by window.location, hope you understand it :D And i got doubts, that every browser or browserext. is working fine with window.location.

I modified your first code and added async: false, so that the browser will wait for the get response, but here i got also problems if for example apache or something else is not working fine and there is no response, then the browser will stuck. The timeout option for the ajax function wont work with sync